# Typescript model return type of Array.prototype.sort()

Tags: typescript

I have defined a type for "sorted" arrays as follows:

```
type Sorted<T> = T[];
```

So right now it just gives the developer some "awareness" that they need to pass a sorted array of some type and they need to ensure the sorting by themself.

I know that I can't check with Typescript whether an array is sorted. But can I somehow change the return type of `Array.prototype.sort()` to be a sorted array of whatever is put in?

Comment: Google: type branding, emulate nominal types in typescript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to prepend an [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) call signature to `Array.prototype.sort`, like this:

```
declare global {
    interface Array<T> {
        sort(compareFn?: ((a: T, b: T) => number) | undefined): Sorted<T>;
    }
}
```

Here I am using [global augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation) (wrapped with `declare global {...}`) which assumes that your code is in a module.  If your code is not in a module, you can leave out the `declare global` wrapper.

Once you do this, you can see from IntelliSense that calls to `sort()` result in a `Sorted`:

```
const arr = [8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9];
const sortedArr = arr.sort();
// const sortedArr: Sorted<number>;
```

As you wanted.  This is the end of the answer to the question as asked.

---

Unfortunately, since you've defined `Sorted<T>` to be an alias for `T[]`, and because TypeScript's type system is [structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) and not [nominal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system), the compiler really sees no meaningful difference between `Sorted<T>` and `T[]`.  The developer may or may not use IntelliSense to see `Sorted<T>`, there will be no compile-time error if the developer fails to notice this and passes an unsorted array into a function that wants a sorted one:

```
function acceptSorted<T>(sortedArr: Sorted<T>) { }
acceptSorted(arr); // no error
```

If you'd like to prevent this, you can use a [trick called "branding"](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-prevent-two-types-from-being-structurally-compatible) where you add a phantom property to the type that distinguishes a `T[]` from a `Sorted<T>`:

```
type Sorted<T> = T[] & { __sorted: true };
```

By "phantom property" I mean it does not actually exist at runtime.  But the compiler doesn't realize this:

```
function acceptSorted<T>(sortedArr: Sorted<T>) { }
acceptSorted(arr); // error!
// --------> ~~~
// Argument of type 'number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Sorted<number>'.
acceptSorted(sortedArr); // okay
```

This still doesn't do much to enforce that a `Sorted<T>` is actually sorted, since you can modify the list to make it unsorted:

```
sortedArr.reverse()
console.log(sortedArr); // [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 3, 0];
acceptSorted(sortedArr); // no error
```

But I'll stop here without trying to make a truly "safe" `Sorted` type, as it would bring us even further out of scope of the original question.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&module=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wLYQCYFcA2wcAvHAIwBQFMAnmEQMrQzDYA8AKgHwlwcDaAXTgAyOAG84AfSmpmrAFxwYUXEQC+AbirZgCfAEMoRAOb4IAIwP4JFOPbgBLZCygAzAwiIBBKFAM0nDzidg5hcrAAFEgYYEbAAGLIAPxKkZEGShwANHAWWQCUJDzIuBgWwFBFAD5wuMi6bs6sBUpMsKxB2mHqFL0USGjwRlC8-AAcuQBsuQDsuQCsuQDMuQAMuQCcgtqD6HARLNi+o6QjAHSHkQXaAPS3iCj7h6wnbfLspeWVXLtPEIRzuYTJEXsc-Dc4Pc4PwNnBVnAlnAZnB5nBJnBtlQ3PUEDBHCg4J4vGAYO0jkFQR83nByZ1uEVJL1icBSXTsBkIZooQ9KlBoABCCjQgC0YvFYp4AD8ZcKHr4TGVgC44BA3Mo6EQAORfCpQIRapyoODICDDVCoRwmZAGCyEZQQOBxfwYYCuVXq2j0OBa9lsXU-LXnCgstkfKkdcFVbnQiAAawCVDBJ3OxgAbpVUMBrgN-oDgRGjidIdD+Jtchi0SikQi1jsQwgSWTw8muTyTY6+dA4EA)

Comment: Thanks, I haven't used it so far and can still change it so I will use the branding trick :)

Answer (score 1):

What about a type and a function combination?

```
type SortedList<T> = T[];

function SortedList<T extends string | number>(arr: T[]): SortedList<T> {
    return arr.sort();
}

const names = SortedList<number>([]);
```